# How to use glob.glob function with pre-define path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I want to use my pre-define path in `glob` function like
code:

```
import glob
import os
list_of_files = glob.glob('/Jaymin/MAC Report/*.txt')
latest_file= max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
```

but instead of this I have path stored in my variable like:

```
My_path=/Jaymin/MAC Report
```

so how can I replace `my_path` variable to the path ?
like:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob(MY_PATH'/*.txt')
```

Comment: Are you just looking for how to concatenate two strings in Python? That's just `+`. (You might want to consider formatting instead, like `f'{MY_PATH}/*.txt`, but concatenation would work fine here too.)

Comment: I want to open latest edited text file.

Comment: Now i can do with put pat name in Os.childr( path name) and then try to use only simle glon.glob function it is working now