# Using implicit path name argument in glob

Tags: python-3.x, glob

I am using `glob.glob()` to read all the png files in a directory. This is what I am using now

```
for filename in glob.glob('D:\test_files\**\*.png',recursive=True):
    ...
```

Image files are kept in sub folders in `test_files`. The code will be used  by someone else within another thousands of lines of codes. Hence, the directory should be defined somewhere else in the code as a string. Also I would like to change *.png by using another for loop. So, I need something like

```
for filename in glob.glob('imagepath'+'extension',recursive=True):
    ...
```

where imagepath is defined somewhere else in the code and extension is kept in a list. Can I use the `glob.glob()` method in this way?

Comment: Side-note: I'm extremely skeptical that your original code works as written. There is a `\t` in your path, and you didn't use a raw string literal, so that string is actually `'D:<TAB>est_files\**\*.png'`. *Always* use raw string literals for Windows paths and regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644352/how-to-use-glob-glob-function-with-pre-define-path). I define the path like `path = 'D:\test_files\**'` and keep the extensions in a list like `imgExtentions =['\*.jpg', '\*.png']`. Then simply I use glob:

```
for extension in imgExtentions:
        for filename in glob.glob(path+extension,recursive=True):
```